# Loading Fusion Charts Upon Clicking Button in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, fusioncharts

I am trying to show my fusion chart in a specific area specially where i am calling the CreateChart function in my aspx file upon clicking a button.  The way I have it  right now is that the chart loads as soon as the page loads but what I would like to see is the chart only loads when the button is clicked.  I have tried different ways but not able to get it right since I am not so familiar with fusion charts.  Thanks
Here is my ASPX file:

```
<table class="style1">

<td class="style8">
                <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Height="29px" Text="Button" 
                    Width="158px" onclick="btnClick_Click" />
            </td>

 <td class="style4" colspan="2">
               <% =CreateChart() %> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and here is my code behind:

```
public string CreateChart()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sqlStatement = "select   Status1, Count(Status1) as TotalCount from  MyTable where Closing_Date =  '" + txtStartClosingDate.Text + "' and Closing_Date <= '" + txtEndClosingDate.Text + "' and Status1 is not null group by  Status1";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string strXML;
        strXML = "<graph labelDisplay='auto' useEllipsesWhenOverflow='1' decimals='2' decimalPrecision='0' showValues='1' enablesmartlabels='0' showlabels='0'  legendAllowDrag='1' numberSuffix=' Days' showLegend='1' pieSliceDepth='45' formatNumberScale='0'>";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            strXML += "<set name='" + reader["Category"].ToString() + "' value='" + reader["AvgNumbers"].ToString() + "' />";
        }
        strXML += "</graph>";
        return FusionCharts.RenderChart("../FusionCharts/Pie2D.swf", "ChartID", strXML, "FactorySum", "450", "450", false, false);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Instead of

```
<td class="style4" colspan="2">
           <% =CreateChart() %> </td>
```

use

```
<td class="style4" colspan="2">
           <asp:Literal mode="PassThrough" runat="server" ID="literalPlaceHolder"/> </td>
```

and in the button's event handler

```
public void btnClick_Click(...)
{
       literalPlaceHolder.Text = CreateChart();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bala for your quick response but it does not like "asp:LiteralControl" when i type it; it only shows me "Literal".  Also in the code behind i am getting this error: "literalPlaceHolder does not exist".  I am not sure what else i am missing.  thanks

Comment: @user1858332 sorry.. I made couple edits to fix it.. first, LiteralControl should be Literal as you found; also name= should be ID=